# ActivityManager: Exception thrown when launching activities java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: val.length > 91

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When launching  MainActivity of Application, it's crashing instantly. When I looked up  the adb logs, I was able to find only this,

```
Exception thrown when launching activities in ProcessRecord
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: val.length > 91
  at SystemProperties.set
```

When I looked up the source code of android, I found that this could be the root of the problem [Android Source Code Of SystemProperties.java](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=mayloon-runtime-master/com.intel.jsdroid/src/android/os/SystemProperties.java). It contains a max value limit of 91.

```
    public static final int PROP_VALUE_MAX = 91; 
    public static String get(String key) { 
        if (key.length() > PROP_NAME_MAX) { 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("key.length > " + PROP_NAME_MAX); 
        } 
        return native_get(key); 
    }
```

When I give it a guess, i found that, my application's **package name is 108 characters** long. And when I changed my app's **package name to 60 characters**, it worked without any problem.

What could be the issue?
This happens only on **Asus Zenfone 2 (Lolipop 5.0)** model.

There is not problem in any other devices. We are receiving a lot of negative rating due to this problem.

> Our app already have 15K downloads in the play store. **so changing the
>   app's package name is not an option for me.** Please help

**Update**

To be more precise, there is

***no issue in all the android phones we tested other than Asus Zenfone    Series***

As mentioned by  @ViswanathLekshmanan in the comments, I changed the location of MainAcitivity.java file to a lower path.

ie, the original full packagename was :- **"com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seasonal_photo_comments.activities.MainActivity"**

I changed it to:- **"com.fourbigbrothers.mtm.activities.MainActivity"**

Still not working. I've put some logs in **onCreate of the MainActivity**, but the code execution is not reaching there at all. So I've no idea where to put a try/catch block as mentioned in some answers.

Would there be any solution using the android ndk? And sorry if it'a a dumb question, I'm completely lost.

**This is the relevant part of the manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seasonal_photo_comments" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:name="com.fourbigbrothers.boilerplate.base.FbbApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FbbApp" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seasonal_photo_comments.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/launcherActivityName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/MainActivityTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: It is an extract from android source code, I Updated the question with the relevant link.

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake that I deleted comment, Did you figure out on which moment this was thrown, I mean In launching of specific Activities or   in start of application itself, Some more hints if possible.

Comment: You can't only change the base package name of Application. you can alter the sub packages. Change the class to a lower package :)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand, does 

the package name is of application is 'com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seasonal_photo_comments'

so the full path to my activity class is , 'com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seasonal_photo_comments.activities.MainActivity'

how can i decrease it? Thanks.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna, The app crashes on the launching MainActivity, not of application start, I tried creating another launcher activity, but it is till the same.

Comment: What's the rest of that call stack? There must be some reason the crash isn't seen on all devices...

Comment: @AkhilSekharan can you provide input of `SystemProperties.set`?

Comment: It looks like the system might be setting the package-name as a system property on the Asus Zenfone 2. If so, then you will *not* be able to fix this unless you change your package-name or Asus pushes an update. Just speculation with what info you've provided.

Comment: @AkhilSekharan [backtick](https://www.google.pl/search?q=backtick&oq=backtick).  I can bet you wanted backtick to do `this` in your comment.

Comment: @AkhilSekharan is it possible to share some demo code with stacktrace?

Comment: @AkhilSekharan  did you tried creating an Launcher activity on package `com.fourbigbrothers` ?

Comment: Why do you have a SystemProperty with a name greater than 92 characters? That is a severe overkill. Also what are you using SYstemProperties for? ALso could you post the full stacktrace instead of a snippet?

Comment: After changing package name it should work. On that time what is error generating? Is it same same as before ? I think this time error will be another. Would you please share the log again? @AkhilSekharan

Comment: Sorry for a delayed reply. I don't have access to the device right now. Once I get my hands on the device, I'll updated the question. As a temporary fix for Asus phones, I've updated the package name of our app from 'com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seasonal_photo_comments' to 'com.fbb.malayalam_text_pic_editor_meme_troll_font_comment' and add it to play store in another name. It looks like @JaredRummler is correct. As I remember, the stack trace only 5 lines of error. The top two lines are in the question.

Comment: @AkhilSekharan I posted my comment as an answer (hoping for the bounty, hehe).

Comment: any chance you can post your manifest?

Comment: I also faced this type of issue in my HTC device

Answer (score 7):

### For the first look

Property system is an important feature on android. It runs as a service and manages system configurations and status. All these configurations and status are properties. A property is a key/value pair, both of which are of string type.
From the sense of function, it's very similar to windows registry. Many android applications and libraries directly or indirectly relies on this feature to determine their runtime behavior. For example, adbd process queries property service to check if it's running in emulator. Another example is the `java.io.File.pathSeparator` returns the value stored in property service.

#### How property system works

The high level architecture of property system is shown as following.

[image]

#### Regarding to your problem.

I strongly recommend to you over walk the proposed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36873892/2956344).
Why?

Look at the [property_service.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/lollipop-release/init/property_service.c#208). This is a class that will called whe you execute `SystemProperties.set` method in native. If you trying to set native_set(key,val) you will not get a positive result due to [is_legal_property_name](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/lollipop-release/init/property_service.c#182) method, that check property rules on the native level.

> When I give it a guess, i found that, my application's package name is 108 characters long. And when I changed my app's package name to 60 characters, it worked without any problem.

Just a guess. Look to `SystemProperties` like an analogue of SharedPreference in Android. You don't need a set full path to your Activity as `key`. Just put a Name. Or with prefex or something like this.

#### Update

After several searches I found a [source](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/sys/system_properties.h) of Native SystemProperties file. He also defines `92` as max length of **value**, and `32` as a max length of **key**. So this is a restriction on the Linux low level.
You can fix this only by cut your `key` value (`<package_name>`.MainActivity in your case)

#### For future searches :

http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-property-system.html

Comment: Thank you for the info. If it's a low level issue, why is the issue happening in Asus Zenfone series only. All other phones we have tested are working.

Comment: Asus Zenfone uses an Intel Atom cpu instead of a classical ARM-based cpu like other smartphones. Maybe that is the reason why they made some changes on the low level code to match the different instruction set? Just guessing

Comment: @AkhilSekharan I will continue search about this.

Comment: "I strongly recommend to you over walk the proposed answer." The proposed answer would not work. An app does not have permission to set a system property. While your graphic is neat, this answer is not helpful IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

A third-party application does not have permission to set a system property. Therefore, the most likely cause of the crash is that the system is setting the package-name as a value for a system property.

Other answers are correct in that the max value of a system property is 92 characters and the max key is 32 characters. However, your app is not setting the system property.

There isn't much you can do to resolve this issue on your end. I would open an issue with Asus and consider changing your package-name (perhaps only for the Asus Zenfone 2). Unfortunately, as you are already aware, you would need to publish a new app if you changed the package-name. Hopefully Asus pushes an update that fixes this issue. Also, a good reason to consider the length of a package-name before releasing to production :)

Answer (score 1):

Tricky problem...next time shorter package names :)

Did you try to change only the package of activities.MainActivity?

like:

```
com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seas‌​onal_photo_comments.a.MA
```

If that solves the problem you could create a tool (in gradle, java, python or whatver) to rename all classes/packages of your project using Base64 to use the minimum number of characters possible before building the project.

Comment: I've tried using shorter names. But didn't worked :(

Comment: I've updated the package name of our app from 'com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seas‌​onal_photo_comments' to 'com.fbb.malayalam_text_pic_editor_meme_troll_font_comment' and add it to play store in another name. I guess, just bad luck.

Comment: Yes pretty bad luck!

Answer (score 1):

For the first lookProperty system is an important feature on android. 
It runs as a service and manages system configurations and status. All these configurations and status are properties. A property is a key/value pair, both of which are of string type.From the sense of function, it's very similar to windows registry. Many android applications and libraries directly or indirectly relies on this feature to determine their runtime behavior.

For example, adbd process queries property service to check if it's running in emulator. Another example is the java.io.File.pathSeparator returns the value stored in property service.How property system worksThe high level architecture of property system is shown as following.Regarding to your problem.I strongly recommend to you over walk the proposed answer. Why?Look at the property_service.h. This is a class that will called whe you execute SystemProperties.set method in native. If you trying to set native_set(key,val) you will not get a positive result due to is_legal_property_name method, that check property rules on the native level.When I give it a guess, i found that, my application's package name is 108 characters long. And when I changed my app's package name to 60 characters, it worked without any problem.Just a guess.

Look to SystemProperties like an analogue of SharedPreference in Android. You don't need a set full path to your Activity as key. Just put a Name. Or with prefex or something like this.UpdateAfter several searches I found a source of Native SystemProperties file. He also defines 92 as max length of value, and 32 as a max length of key. So this is a restriction on the Linux low level. You can fix this only by cut your key value (.

MainActivity in your case)For future searches : http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-property-system.html

Answer (score -1):

**As you don't want to change the package name** whose length is 108 character more than 91. So you have to bypass the exception. If this error occurs then it will be bypassed for your coding section.

### Root Cause Analysis:

You have missed the section where the error generates. As it said **val.length > 91**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: val.length > 91
```

So, the error is generating from blocked portion.

```
/**
 * Set the value for the given key. 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the key exceeds 32 characters 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the value exceeds 92 characters 
 */ 
public static void set(String key, String val) { 
    if (key.length() > PROP_NAME_MAX) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("key.length > " + PROP_NAME_MAX); 
    }
```

> ```
>     if (val != null && val.length() > PROP_VALUE_MAX) { 
>         throw new IllegalArgumentException("val.length > " + 
>             PROP_VALUE_MAX); // Error is generating from here
>     }
> ```

```
    native_set(key, val); 
}
```

---

### Solution:

If you check the upon method, then you will get that it checks first the key's length and then it checks the value length. After that it set key and value.

So for our case, our goal is to set key and value. If length of value exceeds 91 character then it gives `IllegalArgumentException`. So I need to bypass according to `value` not key.

In `MainActivity`, I first search which calls this portion and generates error, then we have to bypass it. Bypassing code is given below. I have not tested the code but it will be look like below. If you are not providing sample code, So I just give the mechanism. Hope you will cope it up with your code.

```
try {
....
// MainActivity.java's portion code which calls the method and causes the error
....
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    if (e instanceof IllegalArgumentException) { // bypass IllegalArgumentException
        .......
        if (key.length < 32) { // It checks that if the IllegalArgumentException is caused for key, then it throws error. It defines that it will be bypassed only for val.length()
            native_set(key, val); //native_set is called without checking length of value
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

> N.B: If you provide minimum sample code and full stacktrace log then
>   it will be better to give appropriate answer.

---

### UPDATE:

Another way you can implement. You can change the MainActivity to SecondMainActivity. Then you will create a new MainActivity(launcher Activity) with minimized package name. Then this newly created MainActivity will call SecondMainActivity.

Please have a try and keep me updated.

Comment: So you call this all proper solution?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I have just tried to bypass the issue. Nothing else

Comment: Actually, MainActivity is not opening at all. my code is not reaching to onCreate method of MainActivity at all.

Comment: After changing package name it should work. On that time what is error generating? Is it same same as before ? I think this time error will be another. Would you please share the log again? @AkhilSekharan

Comment: @AkhilSekharan I have also updated my answer. Would you please give a try for that and let me know.

Comment: @SkyWalker, I created new activity at com.fourbigbrothers.mtm.activities.TempActivity and the same error happens. I guess its my bad luck to give a long package name for the app

Comment: @AkhilSekharan have you tried with both package name <92? Make sure that TempActivity   and MainActivity all are less than 92 and what the error generates for experimental purpose?

Comment: When I tried, MainActivity was at 'com.fourbigbrothers.malayalam_troll_greetings_maker_edit_movie_images_font_seasonal_photo_comments.activities.MainActivity'
the TempActivity was at 'com.fourbigbrothers.mtm.activities.TempActivity'. I havent tested the scenario of having both Activities at lower package name. I'll give it a try tomorrow and will let you know. Thanks. And as a temprory fix I've changed the package name of my app to 'com.fbb.malayalam_text_pic_editor_meme_troll_font_comment' and add it to play store as another app.

Comment: OK. Lets have a try then.